How can I load a gguf model and retrieve its weights using llama_cpp python?
I'm trying to compress quantized gguf models to reduce storage space and was wondering if it is possible to retrieve the weights of a model after loading it with llama_cpp.
As far as I know I'm only able to check the model size and number of parameters for a model using llama_cpp.
